# What does "up to a proportionality factor" mean?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes in physical derivations, I come across that some property or quantity is "measured" or "approximated" or "calculated" up to a proportionality factor. But what does this really mean?

An example is found in "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by Sakurai and Napolitano on page 2, at the end of the paragraph which ends on the middle of the page (easily viewed in the amazon's "Look inside" feature, see link at the bottom).

[https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Quantum-Mechanics-Pearson-International-ebook/dp/B00IZ0G4BG/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1484946267&sr=1-1&keywords=modern+quantum+mechanics+sakurai](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IZ0G4BG)

Comment: You have understood my point. You could put this in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the author was too lazy to figure out the factor...

Seriously, there can be several valid reasons for leaving out constant factors:

1. In a theoretical derivation, the factor might only be accessible through experiment so is not of interest in this context.
2. In many experiments you do not measure a quantity directly but through a signal which is proportional to that quantity. The proportionality factor might not be known and might be dependent on the actual experimental setup (so is not universal).
   In a plot of data of a physical quantity $f(x)=cg(x)$  ($c$ is the proportionality constant) which depends on a parameter $x$ you often see that the vertical axes is actually normalised to e.g. $f(0)$ so that what is plotted is $f(x)/f(0)$ which does not depend on the proportionality constant.
3. One can take the view that constant factors only correspond to the choice of units and are therefore not important in general discussions.
4. Normalization factors are also often left out for convenience.
5. Avoiding cluttering of equations in order to point out the important functional dependence between quantities

Comment: +1 a better answer than mine., esp. The first line.   The second worst phrase in a textbook is "Obviously" or "We leave that as an exercise..."

Comment: @Countto10 The third worst phrase is "Note that ..." followed by a random mathematical identity with no justification--the kind that would take 10 pages to prove how obvious it is.

Comment: I self study, so this site is a godsend, it has stopped me pulling out my (remaining ) hair.  Sometimes the writers are lazy, sometimes they are just showing off.

Answer (score 3):

It means that there is a relationship between quantities, but you don't care about the constant.

For example: for a circle, the area is proportional to the radius squared.

You would write this as $ A \propto r^2 $. So, "area" and "radius squared" are the same, up to a proportionality constant. The proportionality constant being, as you probably know, $ \pi$. So to be really precise, $A = \pi r^2$.

---

The reason why you will see physics books write like this is because we often care about the relationship between quantities. We care about questions such as "How is energy $E$ related to the momentum $p$?". Whether there is a $\pi $ or $\frac{32}{\pi}$ or whatever in the formula is not the interesting physics part of it.

Answer (score 2):

It means you don't have to make equations more cluttered with constant terms than they need to be. Sometimes the proportionality factor can be a lot of terms. You want the important variables to be highlighted, and it's easier to make estimates without having to use the entire equation.

Answer (score 0):

Further to earlier answers, if $y=kx$ we might not care what $k$ is because we're only testing whether $\dfrac{y_2}{y_1}=\dfrac{x_2}{x_1}$ (in analogy to not caring about a constant term in a conserved total), or because we prove $y=0$ by showing $x=0$.